# How to Prevent creating SQL Server databases on C drive

Tags: sql-server

People install 3rd party applications which may create databases on C: instead of the default data/log drive. How to prevent database creation on C:

Comment: This isn't a database question, this is an infrastructure question. You should try asking on [NetworkEngineering.StackExchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [StackOverflow.com](https://www.StackOverflow.com/) possibly instead.

Answer (score 1):

> How to prevent database creation on C:

SQL Server must have permissions to a folder to create a database there.  Revoke the permissions and the CREATE DATABASE will fail.

For a default instance you'll see that the NT Service\MSSQLSERVER has full control over the DATA folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLXX.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

revoke that and databases can't be created there.

Comment: I'm not a fan of DDL triggers, but that can be used as well.